# Compiler error "E2003 Undeclared identifier"

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-xe

In this code:

```delphi
uses 
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, 
  Forms, Dialogs, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, 
  IdTCPClient, IdIOHandler, IdGlobal, StdCtrls;

function WaitForCommand(args: Pointer): Cardinal; stdcall;
begin
  while client.Connected do
    if not HandleResponse(client.IOHandler) then
      break;
  Result := 0;
end;
```

I have this error:

> [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(159): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'HandleResponse'

Comment: This is simply because you haven't declared any function named `HandleResponse`, or because you haven't included the right unit in the `uses` clauses.

Comment: uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient,
  IdIOHandler, IdGlobal, StdCtrls;

Comment: The problem is that `HandleResponse` isn't a function that comes with Delphi. It is a function you must write yourself!

Comment: This is a bit like asking your butler, "Please give me my frogumator." without first telling your butler what your "frogumator" *is*, and then becoming angry with the poor butler for not understanding your request.

Comment: How should I write it? What can I provide you to help me out?

Comment: I have no idea. If your app is a server that controls traffic lights, your `HandleResponse` maybe should change a light from red to green. Or if your app is a media server, maybe the command is to pause the current playback. Your only option is to hire a computer programmer to write the program (and of course you must also tell him the application's specification and requirements). Computer programs cannot write themselves (yet).

Comment: Where have you got the code from? Prpbably you'll find your `HandleResponse` there too.

Comment: Solved I defined the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How to understand messages?

Let's read it in parts:

1. > [DCC Error]

   DCC is the Delphi Compiler, so it is about our code, not about linking or packaging.
2. > Unit1.pas

   The file in which the error occurred. Normally Delphi's editor automatically  display this file to you.
3. > (159)

   The line in which an error occurred. Normaly Delphi's editor automatically puts your text cursor into this line.
4. > E2003

   That's is the code of the error in case any further text is unavailable. It is like HTTP's status `404` is a code (with the actual text "Not Found" for it) or like a traffic's light `red` is a code (without any further text telling you to stop).
5. > Undeclared identifier:

   At this point the compiler does not know how to interpret what is now named. And and even cannot tell you if it is a missing function, a missing type, or else - hence the overall term "identifer".
6. > 'HandleResponse'

   Normally Delphi's editor automatically puts your text cursor in the line of issue at the start of the text that cannot be understood.

### What could you do?

It is undeclared. Declare it. However, only you can know what you want. You could

- declare a type:

  ```delphi
  type
    HandleResponse= Boolean;
  ```
- define a function:

  ```delphi
  function HandleResponse(h: TIdIOHandler): Boolean;
  begin
    result:= FALSE;
  end;
  ```
- import a function from a DLL:

  ```delphi
  function HandleResponse(p: Pointer): LongBool; stdcall; external 'any.dll';
  ```
- add the unit that might already have it:

  ```delphi
  uses
    WhatIsMissingSoFar;
  ```

...or do other things I yet have to remember. But I'm sure you understand that in these 3 examples the **identifier** `HandleResponse` is now **declared**. I don't have to tell you that declarations must be done before using it, right?

Comment: Solved I defined the function.

Comment: How about accepting this answer then? Did you take the [tour]?

Comment: I would like to do it but I don't have 15 points.

Comment: Not upvoting! Accepting. Take the tour again.